# How to Get Windows 10 To Show All The Wireless Connections' Details?

Tags: windows

I've noticed that Windows 10 no longer shows all the wireless connections' details like how it does in Windows 7.

In Windows 7 when you hover the mouse cursor over to any wireless connections on the network connection list, it automatically displays the wireless connection's details.

Does anyone know how to make Windows 10 do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid this is not available in Windows 10.

And you can only right-click the wireless adapter, and click the status.

Then you can click details to see details about the wireless connection.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the confirmation of Windows 10 no longer displaying other detected connection details. That's a shame. I assume that this change is make due to security reason. : -\